# Metal back on a slide in electric range

Tags: electrical, appliances, oven

Is it necessary to keep the metal back on a slide in electric range.  I have a fan that comes up from the back of the counter and it needs a little more room.  The new range will not slide back as far as it needs to due to the metal covering hitting the fan motor.  It needs about 1/2 inch.   It looks like the back was taken off my old range.

Comment: Are you talking about the metal back that covers up the electrical connections between the wire and the oven?  If so, yes, that absolutely needs to be there.  You wouldn't want someone reaching back there and instead finding 240V across their fingertips...

Comment: The back of a slide in is inaccessible to anyone. Still probably need to leave the panel in place, it is required to achieve a zero clearance to combustibles rating.